# Wordpress Resources not loading randomly

Tags: php, wordpress, get

Have a site that suddenly started giving a lot of errors in the console internal error 500, seems it randomly cannot find files, refreshing the page gives a different set of files it cannot find and sometimes it just manages to find all the files, tried going through any plugins to see if there was a specific one causing it but i cant seem to find it. so i am trying to find out the way to track it down to fix it. [console](http://prntscr.com/b4bmb4) debug.log file has this message only repeated 8 times :
[15-May-2016 16:41:35 UTC] PHP Notice:  get_currentuserinfo is **deprecated** since version 4.5! Use wp_get_current_user() instead. in /home/sites/nickritson.co.uk/public_html/edeals/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3658

things i have tried. switching themes, turning off all plugins, replacing wp-admin and include folders with clean install files, renaming the htaccess file, created a php.ini with the following values based on this: [php.ini for wordpress values](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/increase-memory-limit/), wp-config, upped the memory limit. spoke to hosting provider they just said to change the limit in php.ini but that has not fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The console by itself cannot give a good indication of any errors. One way to check to see what the problem may be is to try and find any log files. In Wordpress you will need to turn on the PHP/Wordpress Error Logging. You will need to edit your wp-config.php file with this line (or change it to true if you have it):

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

You will then find any errors in:

```
/wp-content/debug.log
```

Then you can edit your question with any errors you find, which will show the details about cause of the error 500 you are getting.